# jQuery prompt before submitting a form, PHP distinguishing which button was used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, events

Good morning everyone.
I have problem with displaying user a prompt using sweetalert (that's kinda irrelevant)

Simplified HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $wid; ?>"> 
    <button type="submit"  name="submit1" class="btn btn-success">Submit #1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn btn-warning">Submit #2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger "onclick="remove()">REMOVE()</button>
</form>
```

PHP that form is submited to. I have to distinguish between buttons used so simplified:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    //do stuff
} elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    //do second stuff
}
```

Finally JS code that displays the prompt:

```
function remove() {
    var id = <?php echo $wid ?>;
    swal({
        title: "Sure?",
        type: "warning",
    }).then(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Removed!",
        });
        removeRow();
    });
    return false;
}

function removeRow() {
    var id = <?php echo $wid ?>;
    window.location = 'delete.php?&id=' + id;
}
```

However I cannot do the same prompt with those two submit buttons. 
What's the issue there:

1. It has to be submit button otherwise PHP won't recognise which
   button was used to submit
2. When i click submit button form automatically submits before "reading" javascript code (what's kinda logic) but even though I stop the event and then try to .submit() with jQuery it wont work out because I cannot submit a form from button-level so form won't pass name of button that was used to be submitted - won't work

How can i **show user prompt** and it **holds submitting untill users accepts warning** and yet be able to **distinguish which button** was used to submit it (so php get's submitted button name)?

Comment: Sorry, i removed it while writing question by accident.

Comment: I suggest you to use ajax to perform this operation. Because you have several buttons and they must do different actions

Comment: It still gives me no way of displaying prompt to user since form will be submitted after clicking button nevertheless. Even if I do something like this:
 `$('#submit1').click(function(){
   $('#formW').attr('action', 'page1');
});


$('#submit2').click(function(){
   $('#formW').attr('action', 'page2');
});`

Comment: if you view the html source in http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ you'll see that you can use `document.querySelector('ul.examples li.message button').onclick = function(){
 swal("Here's a message!");
};` as per the "A basic message" example. Or, create a function that will fire up something and based on adding id's to your buttons. I'm thinking outloud here of course. See the other examples also and its source.

Comment: To prompt user use **if (confirm('are you sure')) {}**

Comment: It works, sure but it won't give user ability to chose whether or not they want to submit. It displays prompt and then submit's the form anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited PHP into two separate files.
Afterwards I added two listeners on click on both of buttons. I removed submit type of them and then added jQuery code:

```
$( "#submit1" ).click(function() {
var id = <?php echo $wid ?>;
    swal({
        title: "Sure?",
        type: "warning",
    }).then(function() {
        swal({
            title: "Success!",
        });
        $('#formW').attr('action', 'script.php?id='+id);
        $('#formW').submit();
    });
    return false;
});
```